# Handling Many Unexpected States with except

Tags: python, flask

I am creating a server with Flask and it has quite a few routes. Most routes require a specific state, such as "logged in" or "process started". All of my functions and methods in packages will throw certain type of exceptions when the specific state is not matched. At the end my code ends up like this:

```
@app.route("/sayHello")
def sayHello():
    try:
        name = get_session_data("user", "name")

        # Some other stuff that throw meaningful exceptions

        return someTemplate

    except NotLoggedIn:
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for("login"))

    except UserNotReadyToSayHello:
        return "You are not ready to say hello!", status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST

    except UserHelloMessageNotDefined:
        return "You did not set up a greeting message!", status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST

    except ConnectionToDatabaseFailed:
        return "Cannot access database", status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR

    except UnexpectedError:
        return "Something happened", status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
```

Of course this is just an example I made up to demonstrate the problem, however it is more or less equivalent to the actual code.

This made programming the routes much easier than checking everything with `if` statements everywhere, however I ended up with a lot of `except` cases to the point where PyLint is telling me

> Too many return statements (9/6)

How should I handle this situation? A lot of routes actually share a very similar sets of `except` cases.

Answer (score 1):

## Handling "too many" return statements.

If your linter tells you, that you have too many return statements, this is a *hint*. A linter is supposed to  *support* you in writing quality code.
If however your code needs that specific exception handling this is what you need to implement and you can ignore the linter's hint.
I am not sure whether you can break down the code into several methods, each handling only a part of the possible exceptions, since you decided not to share this essential part of the code with us (`# Some other stuff that throw meaningful exceptions`).

## Re-use of exception handlers

If you want to re-use the exception handlers, you can refactor them into the `__exit__` method of an appropriate context manager.
Then you can do something like:

```
@app.route("/sayHello")
def sayHello():
    with ErrorHandler as error_handler:
        name = get_session_data("user", "name")

        # Some other stuff that throw meaningful exceptions

        return someTemplate

    return error_handler.retval
```

And re-use the respective context manager `ErrorHandler` accordingly.

Comment: This seems like a good strategy, but I think it won't work when I need to handle one extra exception that is not handled in the error handler.

Comment: Then you can still `try` and `except` it.

Comment: I ended up creating a decorator to handle common exceptions, and the `try..except` block remains inside to catch specific exceptions.